# Custom xmlsitemapprovider can't set Title of sitemapnode?

Tags: sitemap, provider

I created my custom XmlSiteMapProvider. Works out great but I want to be able to change the Title of the SiteMap also in there. However I get exceptions that Title is suddenly readonly while the property has a setter when viewing in the Object Browser. Anyone can explain this behavior?

I've been trying to create a new node, use the RemoveNode method to delete the current one and then use the AddNode method. However when I use the method with 1 parameter it starts to complain (exception that the parentNode can't be null). If I use the method overload with 2 parameters and want to pass in the parentNode of the node to delete it's also null. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible due to optimizations by Microsoft. The base class to be used instead is StaticSiteMapProvider.